# Use redux to track recent viewed product, is this ok?

Tags: html, reactjs, cookies, product, render

I am a newbie in ReactJS. To show the recent viewed product, many pages say that we will use cookie. But I am using redux to do it. My idea is: each time visitor open the product page, we will dispatch information of the product (suchs as ID) to store of redux. Then, we only need to get data from store. I don't see any one saying about this way so I am a bit worried about my solution. In case it's better to use cookies, could you please advise a link/ website to learn about it. I search many page but there's no details so it's so hard. Thank you so much.

Here my code:

1. Store;

```
const Viewed = [];
const Viewed_reducer = (init = Viewed, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_TO_VIEWED":
            if (init.indexOf(action.id) === -1) {
                init.push(action.id)
            }
            return init;
        default:
            return init;
    }
}
const All_reducer = redux.combineReducers({
    Viewed: Viewed_reducer
});
const Store = redux.createStore(All_reducer);
export default Store;
```

2. Product page, this will dispatch the product ID to Store each time visitor open:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import urlSlug from "url-slug";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import ProductsInfo from '../../../Data/ProductInfo';
import RecentViewed from './RecentViewed/RecentViewed';
const ProductDetail = (props) => {
    const nameSlug = props.match.params.slug;
    const {dispatch} = props;
    const Product = ProductsInfo.find((product) => {
        return urlSlug(product.name) === nameSlug
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({type: "ADD_TO_VIEWED", id: Product.id})
    },[dispatch, Product])
    return (
        <section className="product-detail">
            <RecentViewed key={`recent${Product.id}`}/>
        </section>
    );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        Store: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductDetail)
```

3. Component to render the data from Store:

```
import React from "react";
import ProductsInfo from "../../../../Data/ProductInfo";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
const RecentViewed = (props) => {
    const {Viewed} = props.Store;
    let viewedProducts = [];
    Viewed.forEach((id) => {
        ProductsInfo.forEach((product) => {
            if (product.id === id){
                viewedProducts.push(product)
            }
        }) 
    })
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid also-container recent-viewed-container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                    <div className="title">Sản phẩm vừa xem</div>
                    <div className="wrap outside">
                        {viewedProducts.map((product) => {
                                return (
                                    // inside here we will show information of product such as name, image, etc
                                )
                            })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                    );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        Store: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RecentViewed)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to remember the last viewed product for the length of the user's browsing session, then the redux store should be fine.  Just remember that it only exists in-memory, so if the user closes their tab or hard-refreshes the page, the store isn't persisted and you'll lose any information there.

Setting it in a cookie will make the information survive a refresh or close/reopen, since cookies are persisted between sessions (assuming you're not using a session cookie).